# Using git in iPhone projects

Tags: iphone, xcode, svn, git

I have been doing iphone projects using git but I noticed that I got tons of conflicts. When using svn this wasn't happening and merges were less frequent.

Xcode needs the user to add a file by hand. For example adding a new image. When this happens an xml get modified. This xml file is one of the ones that git gets conflict and svn doesn't.

Anyone using git with xcode projects is doing something to fix this?

Comment: Maybe an explanation of what kind of conflicts? I know lots of iPhone devs using Git without problems like this.

Comment: @Abizern: ok, I will edit the question.

Comment: It is true, changes by multiple parties within the xcodeproj do frequently trigger merge conflicts that one has to resolve manually. AFAIK, that is just something we have to live with, or dont we?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are having conflicts on files that shouldn't be version controlled in the first place (eg. generated code or binaries). If this is the case, you should remove then from the repository and add their names to `.gitignore` to ensure they won't be added in the future.

Comment: Not really. Xcode needs the user to add a file by hand. For example adding a new image. When this happens an xml get modified. This is the one which gets conflicts.

Comment: It would be great if you mentioned that in the question.

Answer (score 2):

although there are similarities, git's commit is not identical to svn's commit.

git has a different workflow, and you can commit, merge, fetch, push at different stages. the additional stages are *features*.

if you want to avoid this: fetch, merge, resolve conflicts, commit, and push every time you want to do what you know as a svn update and commit cycle. this process will enforce the incremental revision model of svn -- git doesn't use an incremental revision model (another git feature).

it's not a problem with git, the systems use different workflows, and git has features you'll eventually really like once you learn to get out of the svn mindset.

git commits are local until pushed to the remote.

Comment: I know how git works and I use it almost every day but somehow svn gets less conflicts than git when working with iphone. Just want to know why or how to solve it.

Comment: @Macarse i am not seeing inexplicable conflicts per commit, but i *did* when i was learning to use git (coming from svn and cvs). if you are sure you understand git: maybe your commit+push frequency has changed, or your client has some bugs??? for most people, it's likely that they don't fully understand the git workflow (yet).

Comment: Not my case unfortunately. I was willing to know if there was a different merge algorithm, or something like that.

Comment: i'm stating the obvious at this point: in the example you provided, you fetch, merge, add the image to the project, commit the project, then push the commit to the remote. it's the same as you'd do with svn to avoid conflicts to the xcode project. the project is a bit fragile/easy to create conflicts when multiple people are editing it, so you end up throwing away changes and reapplying them often before committing. but that workflow is required with svn too. you have to keep the project up to date and commit when changed to avoid conflicts. i'm just not seeing anything unusual in this regard.

Comment: Try it out: Create an iphone project, commit/push it; make someone add a file; commit/push; add a different file; update/fetch-merge. You will notice that most of the times svn will merge without issues and git will give you a conflict.